# update a Excel file with a loop

Tags: java, excel, loops, date, xls

First of all, thanks for all the answer you could give me.

My problem seems maybe easy but i'm a beginner in Java. I have to update my Excel file with some date. But all the information are send to the excel sheet at the end of the loop instead while i'm in the loop.

```
private void calculateExcelStaffingHistoriqueStockDetail(final List<StockVo> listStock, final WritableSheet sheet, boolean isMois, int jourD, int moisD, int anneeD, int taillePeriode) throws WriteException {

    // Set Excel cell format header
    //final String[] tabDomaine = { "Aucun Domaine", "Contrat/Produit", "Comptabilité", "Rég.Finance", "Sinistre", "Interface" };

    // Create a cell format for Arial 10 point font
    final WritableFont arial10font = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 10);
    final WritableCellFormat arial10format = new WritableCellFormat(arial10font);

    arial10format.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);

    for (int row = 0; row < listStock.size(); row++) {

        final StockVo stock = listStock.get(row);
        String ch = "";
        int i = 0;
        // Vue Mensuel
        if (isMois) {               
            for (i = moisD; i < taillePeriode + moisD; i++) {
                if (i <= 12) {
                    if (i < 10) {
                        ch = "0" + i + "/" + anneeD;
                    } else {
                        ch = i + "/" + anneeD;
                    }
                } else {
                    i = i - 12;
                    if (i < 10) {
                        ch = "0" + (i - 12) + "/" + (anneeD + 1);
                    } else {
                        ch = (i - 12) + "/" + (anneeD + 1);
                    }
                }
                sheet.addCell(new Label(3 + row, 6, ch, arial10format));
            }
        // Le totaux des entrees, livraisons, stock et en attentes de tout les domaines
        sheet.addCell(new Label(1, 7, "Total", arial10format));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(2, 7, "Total", arial10format));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(2, 8, "Stock", arial10format));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(2, 9, "En Attentes", arial10format));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(2, 10, "Entrées", arial10format));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(2, 11, "Sortie", arial10format));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(3 + row, 7, Integer.toString(stock.getStock() + stock.getAttentes() + stock.getEntrees() + stock.getLivraisons()), arial10format));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(3 + row, 8, Integer.toString(stock.getStock()), arial10format));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(3 + row, 9, Integer.toString(stock.getAttentes()), arial10format));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(3 + row, 10, Integer.toString(stock.getEntrees()), arial10format));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(3 + row, 11, Integer.toString(stock.getLivraisons()), arial10format));
        }
    }
}
```

So i would like to update the date I pick in a different Cell. So if i choose 4 months, I must have 01/01/17, 01/02/17, 01/03/17, 01/04/17.

But actually I have this : 01/04/17, 01/04/17, 01/04/17, 01/04/17.

Do you have an idea why the "sheet.addCell(new Label(3 + row, 6, ch, arial10format));" is update at the end and not at each time it pick up a different date ? (PS: in the debug mode, the information are correctly pick, the problem is when I must to send it to the Excel sheet, it only send the last date 4 time rather than 1 date 4 times.

Comment: What is `sheet` in this case? What type of object is it?

Comment: sheet is an Excel file. it allow to put information in a Excel file.

Comment: he asks if its `XSSFSheet` or `HSSFSheet`

Comment: I don't really know sorry, i'm an alternating (student who works in a company) all the application was already developpe, so this part too, my job to improve the app.

Comment: Hmmm, little messy code for persons which didnt code it. I can to suggest you to use `Calendar` and `Simpledate format` instead parsing and computing each part of date manually. Or you should to provide greater scope for better solution. I nothing more, just explain your variables :)

Comment: So i edit the all post by my full function, maybe it is better for you yo look at it

Comment: the 'isMois' is to see if we are in a monthly vue and the else, if it's a weekly vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those you needs an answer this works fine with me.

```
    String ch = "";
    for (int row = 0; row < listStock.size(); row++) {

        final StockVo stock = listStock.get(row);

        // Vue Mensuel
        if (isMois) {               
            //for (int i = moisD; i < taillePeriode + moisD; i++) {
                final int mois = (row % 12) + 1;
                final int annee = row / 12;

                    if (mois <= 9) {

                        ch = "0" + mois + "/" + (anneeD + annee);

                    } else  {
                        ch = mois + "/" + (anneeD + annee);
                    }

                sheet.addCell(new Label(3 + row, 6, ch, arial10format));
```